# How do I repair my user db table in phpmyadmin when I get error message that is is corrupted?

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb

When I try and edit user accounts in phpmyadmin I get the error message "#1034 index for table 'db' is corrupt". The only table 'db' I can see is in the 'mysql' DB. Firstly, is that the table it is referring to? Because when I browse it, it seems fine and I get no errors there.
I am simply clicking the 'user accounts' button in phpmyadmin, at the top. That is how I normally edit users, not directly in a db table. But I cannot get past that. I am wondering whether I need to re-install xampp / apache.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: `REPAIR TABLE mysql.db;`

Comment: Thank you @RickJames This is a good question and you gave a good answer.